# How do you convert a HttpPostedFileBase to an Image?

Tags: image, httppostedfilebase, asp.net-mvc-file-upload

I am using ASP.NET MVC and I've an action that uploads the file. The file is being uploaded properly. But I want width and height of the image. I think I need to convert the `HttpPostedFileBase` to `Image` first and then proceed. How do I do that?

And please let me know if there is another better way to get the width and height of the image.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

I use [`Image.FromStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21zw9ah6) to as follows:

```
Image.FromStream(httpPostedFileBase.InputStream, true, true)
```

Note that the returned `Image` is `IDisposable`.

You'll need a reference to `System.Drawing.dll` for this to work, and `Image` is in the `System.Drawing` namespace.

### Resizing the Image

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but if you happen to be making thumbnails or something similar, you may be interested in doing something like...

```
try {
    var bitmap = new Bitmap(newWidth,newHeight);
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap)) {
        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
        g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        g.DrawImage(oldImage,
            new Rectangle(0,0,newWidth,newHeight),
            clipRectangle, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    }//done with drawing on "g"
    return bitmap;//transfer IDisposable ownership
} catch { //error before IDisposable ownership transfer
    if (bitmap != null) bitmap.Dispose();
    throw;
}
```

where `clipRectangle` is the rectangle of the original image you wish to scale into the new bitmap (you'll need to manually deal with aspect ratio).  The catch-block is typical `IDisposable` usage inside a constructor; you maintain ownership of the new `IDisposable` object until it is returned (you may want to doc that with code-comments).

### Saving as Jpeg

Unfortunately, the default "save as jpeg" encoder doesn't expose any quality controls, and chooses a terribly low default quality.

You can manually select the encoder as well, however, and then you can pass arbitrary parameters:

```
ImageCodecInfo jpgInfo = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders()
    .Where(codecInfo => codecInfo.MimeType == "image/jpeg").First();
using (EncoderParameters encParams = new EncoderParameters(1))
{
    encParams.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, (long)quality);
    //quality should be in the range [0..100]
    image.Save(outputStream, jpgInfo, encParams);
}
```

Comment: Great code snippet!  Why are you disposing of the image in your catch block and then rethrowing the exception instead of just using the finally block?

Comment: because the finally block *always* executes - but the newly created image only needs to be disposed on error.  If no error occurs, the new image was correctly constructed and becomes owned by the calling function - now it's their responsibility to dispose it.

Comment: I'll add an explanation about the try-catch with IDisposable.

Comment: hi, sorry to bring this dead thread alive, was wondering, do u know how i can save the file to a file system? i didn't wanna use the dbase for saving it,just the url maybe. also, im trying to figure out if i want to adjust sizes to 50x100 when the image size is like 150x150.is it recommended to always set the w and h to those numbers or do i just proportionately adjust it meet the limit? thanks!

Comment: This code simply scales the image - you'll need to decide how to crop (`clipRectangle`) and you'll want to ensure the resultant aspect ratio isn't too far off.  To save to the filesystem, simply pass the appropriate stream (in the example, it's named `outputStream`) to the `Save` method.

Comment: When I use Image image = Image.FromStream(item.InputStream, true, true); code I get parameter is not valid exeption. Please tell me , How can i fixx this problem?

Comment: @ElvinArzumanoğlu: you should probably ask a new question if you can't easily solve the problem, because in your own question you can add all the relevant details.  But as a general tip; try saving the stream to disk and reproducing the exception locally from a file stream - if you can do that, you have a fairly small test case and those are always easier to deal with.

Comment: @Eamon,I am blocked for asking question,so I can't ask any question:(.at first my scenario is that I have a dropzone js library(http://www.dropzonejs.com/)for uploading image,what I can upload many images a time,I add these images to my httpPfile in this dropzone upload action and add this to Lis<>,,then I get this uploading files in save button,but in foreach loop when I write previous code I get parameter is not valid exeption,then i think this error means i can write this only first time in post action,then i try convert  httpPoBase to image in dropezone action and so converting work fine

Comment: I don't quite understand what you said, but `httpPostedFileBase.InputStream` is only valid in the request in which the file was posted - in that request you will need to save the data somewhere, and you probably want to do image processing right away too.

Comment: @EamonNerbonne below line of code is not working for me System.Drawing.Image sourceimage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(file.InputStream,true,true);

Comment: @HeemanshuBhalla: it's a standard function; so you might check the docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21zw9ah6 - or ask a new question with more details as to what isn't working.

Answer (score 7):

If you are sure, that the source is image and doesn't need editing, you can do it easily as described [here](http://dotnetqueries.wordpress.com/tag/convert-httppostedfilebase-to-image-using-c-net/)

```
[HttpPost]
public void Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    if (file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        var filename = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

        System.Drawing.Image sourceimage =
            System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(file.InputStream);
    }
}
```

To secure the file is image, add javascript validation to View by adding accept attribute with MIME type to input tag

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*">
```

and jQuery validation script

```
$.validator.addMethod('accept', function () { return true; });
```

The whole solution can be found [here](http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/2013/05/how-to-create-and-editorfor-fileupload.html)