# Upload and display image via database in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddDetails", "UsersDetails", null,
                FormMethod.Post, new
                {
                    encrypt = "multipart/form-data",
                    @class = "form-horizontal",
                    role = "form"
                }))
{ 
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <label for="Picture">Upload Image:</label>
    <input name="Picture" id="Picture" type="file" />
}
```

Controller action:

```
public ActionResult AddDetails(UsersDetailViewModel udv, FormCollection fc, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        try
        {
            string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads"),
                                       Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
            file.SaveAs(path);
            ViewBag.Message = "File uploaded successfully";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "ERROR:" + ex.Message.ToString();
        }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "You have not specified a file.";
    }

    ud.Picture = udv.Picture;

    return View();
}
```

When I try to upload image then in upload input box it contain the whole path as `c:\users\Adi\black.png` but I need only image name as black image.

Comment: This can be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18571709/1646540

Answer (score 0):

`Path.GetFileName` will you the file name with extension (Ex :"black.png").

```
if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
{
   var fileName= Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
   // It's a good idea to remove spaces
   fileName=fileName.Replace(" ","_");
   //If you want to generate a unique filename, you may try something like
   // fileName=Guid.NewGuid().ToString+fileName;

   var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads"),fileName);
   file.SaveAs(path);

   //you can use fileName value to save to user record.
}
```