# Convert from HttpPostedFileBase to image produce error due position

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following controller, which upon receiveing a file from the view generates a thumbnail and saves both, image abd thumbnail to the database:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var logo = new Logo() { LogoGuid = Guid.NewGuid() };
            var clinica = await GetClinicaAsync();

            if (IsClinicNonexistent(clinica))
            {
                db.Logos.Add(logo);
                clinica.LogoGuid = logo.LogoGuid;
            }

            else
                logo = await db.Logos.FirstOrDefaultAsync(l => l.LogoGuid == clinica.LogoGuid);

            logo.LogoImage = GetImage(file);
            logo.Thumbnail = GetThumbnail(file);

            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Arquivos");
    }
```

Which, for the matters of this error calls a method:

```
private byte[] GetThumbnail(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        var image = Image.FromStream(file.InputStream);
        var thumbnailSize = GetThumbnailSize(image);
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        var thumbnail = image.GetThumbnailImage(thumbnailSize.Width, thumbnailSize.Height, null, IntPtr.Zero);
        image.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

        return memoryStream.ToArray();
    }
```

That configuration of code produces an erro while running the line

```
var image = Image.FromStream(file.InputStream);
```

The error is: "System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid."

[image: The error produced]

All documentation that I could refer to, makes me believe that it's all sintatically and logically correct, yet there is the error...

But, tne funny thing is, if a move the conversion line which produces error, do the calling method, specifically to the begining as:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var logo = new Logo() { LogoGuid = Guid.NewGuid() };
            var clinica = await ClinicaAsync();

            var image = Image.FromStream(file.InputStream);
```

There will be no error. Please notice that the convertion line is in the last line of the code just above, thus in the begining of the controller. Again, if I move that line further down, but still in the controller, there will be the error again...

How can I keep the line where it logically belongs, thus in the GetThumbnail method?

Just as an additional reference, the GetImage method is:

```
private byte[] GetImage(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        using (var br = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream))
            return br.ReadBytes(file.ContentLength);
    }
```

Comment: What does `GetImage` do? Is it possible the input file is altered in any way? (i.e. stream position moved)

Comment: @Lennart Stoop I've posted at the end the GetImage, but it only reads the HttpPostedFileBase, doesn't touch it...

Comment: Well, when the `BinaryReader` is disposed of (after the `using` statement) the underlying stream will be closed too. That's causing the issue you're having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you should know is [`Image.FromStream()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.fromstream?view=netframework-4.7.2) requires a stream (`MemoryStream`, `InputStream`, etc.) that hasn't been already read, or the position is reset to beginning using `Seek()` method.

First, try to reset the pointer before calling `GetThumbnail()` method by using `Position` property or `Seek()`:

```
// alternative 1
logo.LogoImage = GetImage(file);
file.InputStream.Position = 0;
logo.Thumbnail = GetThumbnail(file);

// alternative 2
logo.LogoImage = GetImage(file);
file.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
logo.Thumbnail = GetThumbnail(file);
```

If this doesn't work, the possible cause is you're calling `Image.FromStream()` after `HttpPostedFileBase.InputStream` has already used (and disposed) by `BinaryReader` which calls `Dispose()` (the `using` statement automatically called it), thus the exception is thrown.

You can create a copy of `MemoryStream` from `HttpPostedFileBase.InputStream` using [`Stream.CopyTo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.copyto?view=netframework-4.7.2) like below example:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        var logo = new Logo() { LogoGuid = Guid.NewGuid() };
        var clinica = await GetClinicaAsync();

        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        file.InputStream.CopyTo(ms); // copy HTTP stream to memory stream

        if (IsClinicNonexistent(clinica))
        {
            db.Logos.Add(logo);
            clinica.LogoGuid = logo.LogoGuid;
        }

        logo.LogoImage = GetImage(file);
        ms.Position = 0; // make sure the stream is read from beginning
        logo.Thumbnail = GetThumbnail(ms);

        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Arquivos");
}
```

Then `GetThumbnail()` parameter should be changed to accept `MemoryStream` copied from HTTP stream:

```
// get image from memory stream
private byte[] GetThumbnail(MemoryStream file)
{
    var image = Image.FromStream(ms);
    var thumbnailSize = GetThumbnailSize(image);
    var thumbnail = image.GetThumbnailImage(thumbnailSize.Width, thumbnailSize.Height, null, IntPtr.Zero);
    image.Save(file, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

    return file.ToArray();
}
```

**Note:** You can also save the stream as image file on the disk and then read it with `Server.MapPath()` to generate thumbnail.

Related issues:

[Image.FromStream(PostedFile.InputStream) Fails. (Parameter is not valid.) (AsyncFileUpload))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614773/image-fromstreampostedfile-inputstream-fails-parameter-is-not-valid-async)

[How do you convert a HttpPostedFileBase to an Image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171696/how-do-you-convert-a-httppostedfilebase-to-an-image)

Comment: Super :) Working Fine